# Evaluating the limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[x]{1+\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

How to evaluate the following limit?

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[x]{1+\sin(x)}$$

Comment: Have you any conjecture as to what the limit might be, given that $x$ could be very large and $\sin x >0, =0, <0$ - if the limit exists there can only be one value.

Comment: My intuition is bad for this, @MarkBennet , for some reason I suspect the answer is $1$ because it seems that's a reasonable intuitive solution for $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[x]{n},n\in\mathbb R^+$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take $x = 2n\pi + \dfrac{3 \pi}2$ and let $n \to \infty$ to see what the limit is. Then look at $x = n\pi$ and let $n \to \infty$ to see what the limit is.

Now conclude limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I will have to think about this... I'll be back when I have some questions.